# Can I share a Draft App with a Bigcommerce User?

Tags: bigcommerce

We allow for potential customers to use our application inside of a Sandbox environment we have on a separate server. It works fine, but one customer wants to test out our Bigcommerce integration against his store. In our BC developer account we do have a Sandbox version of the app that we have used for testing, but of course it's only permissioned for our store. Is there a way to "share" a draft app with a Bigcommerce user for a temporary time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot share draft apps with other stores at this time. However, you can set your app to allow multiple users and then create a new user account in your sandbox store that you can share with the client for testing. The client will not be able to install the app outside of the sandbox store until it is live in the app marketplace.